# Why does importing a script as module change its variable scope?

Tags: javascript, html

I couldn't find much documentation explaining this. In JS:

```
// fileA.js
const varA = 1

// fileB.js
console.log(varA)
```

In HTML, if it looks like:

```
<script defer src='./fileA.js'></script>
<script defer src='./fileB.js'></script>
```

Then it will print '1', but if in HTML, the script tag is changed to

```
<script defer type='module' src='./fileA.js'></script>
<script defer src='./fileB.js'></script>
```

Then `varA` will not be found. Why is this? The workaround is to use `window.varA` but not sure the logic behind this phenomenon.

Thanks!

Comment: It’s module-scoped.

Comment: Why? because it's how es modules are designed. You may as well ask why you need to put function call arguments in `()`, not all languages need that, but javascript does because that's how it was designed - as for the logic behind it. It's so that modules don't need to be concerned with variables that may be declared in other modules - it's one of the main reasons modules exist, modular code